# How to dynamically indicate groups in an R in plot

Tags: r

This is my data

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
  17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22)
y = c(1, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 9, 6, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9, 
  5, 4, 7)

plot(x, y)
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
fit
abline(fit, col = "black", lwd = "1")
```

I would like to the plot to split the data into two groups, observations above the regression line and and those under the regression line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `predict` to get the fitted value at each x, and then a logical comparison between the observed and fitted to test if they're above or below the line. Then set the colors you plot based on this logical comparison.

```
prediction <- predict(fit)
colors<-ifelse(y>prediction,1,2)
plot(x,y,col=colors)
abline(fit, col= "black",lwd="1")
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I save those two groups? In different data

Comment: `above <- y[y>prediction]` and `below <- y[y<prediction]` might work for you